# return query result only if value of field on associated model is not empty cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3

Let's say I have `ModelA` and `ModelB` in a CakePHP application. The type of association between `ModelA` and `ModelB` is the following:

```
ModelA hasOne ModelB
ModelB belongsTo ModelB
```

I want a find() query on `ModelA` that should return something only if the `number` field of `ModelB` is not empty (return empty otherwise). I tried something like this but my ModelA and ModelB are still returned in the result of the query even if the `number` field of ModelB is empty:

```
$this->ModelA->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Model B' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                 'ModelB.number IS NOT NULL'
            )
        )
    ), 
    'conditions' => array(
        'ModelA.id' => 13
    )
));
```

As you can see above, I put the condition in the `contain` on `ModelB`. I hope it's clear enough what I'm trying to do here. Can anybody help?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried changing the condition from `'ModelB.number IS NOT NULL'` to `array("NOT" => array("ModelB.number" => null))` ?

Comment: Yes I tried, didn't work, the problem is because cake LEFT JOINS ModelA with ModelB, it should be INNER JOIN

Answer (score 1):

You should always check the queries that are executed by CakePHP. By enabling debug level 2, the SQL statements should be visible on your page.

In your case, I *suspect* the `NOT NULL` condition is not specified correctly. It should probably be like this;

```
$this->ModelA->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Model B' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                 'NOT' => array(
                     'ModelB.number' => NULL
                 )
            )
        )
    ), 
    'conditions' => array(
        'ModelA.id' => 13
    )
));
```

Comment: I found the problem, cake does a left join in the query that it executes, an inner join will give me the desired result, how can I change the type of join that cake does automatically?

Comment: @user765368 you can add `'type' => 'INNER'` to your has/belongsTo relations